# How to migrate authentication code from IdentityServer3 in .Net Framework to IdentityServer4 in .Net Core 2.2?

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, identityserver4

I had my Web API application in .Net Framework 4.5.2. Now I am migrating to Web API in .Net Core 2.2.

In *.net framework we used IdentityServer3.AccessTokenValidation* nuget package and used to write like this to authenticate our APIs.

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Map("/api", inner =>
        {
            inner.UseIdentityServerBearerTokenAuthentication(new IdentityServerBearerTokenAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationMode = Microsoft.Owin.Security.AuthenticationMode.Active,
                Authority = "https:/xxx.org/yy/zz",
                ClientId = "some-client-id",
                ClientSecret = "somesecret",
                RequiredScopes = new string[] { "somexxScope" }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

In *.Net Core Startup.cs I am using IdentityServer4.AccessTokenValidation* and I am writting like this, but it is not working. It is throwing 401 Unauthorized error.

```
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_2);

    services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddIdentityServerAuthentication(o =>
    {
        o.Authority = "https:/xxx.org/yy/zz";
        o.ApiName = "some-client-id";
        o.ApiSecret = "somesecret";
        o.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
        });
    }
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();

    app.UseMvc();
}
```

Can you tell me what is the exact replacement of ClientId, ClientSecret and RequiredScopes (basically the IdentityServer3 authentication code part) in IdentityServer4?

Or is there any other way to write the same code in .Net Core 2.2?

Comment: It looks like you configured the client as api. It should look like [this](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/quickstarts/5_hybrid_and_api_access.html#modifying-the-mvc-client).

Comment: @RuardvanElburg The link shows cookie scheme but I need jwt bearer token authentication.. can you help me with that?